# I am trying to retrieve data from an API but am running into an error

Tags: javascript, post

I keep getting the error:

> "Invalid product option length" or "error : ??"

Here is the API link: `https://liveapi.sinalite.com/`

```
fetch("https://liveapi.sinalite.com/price/20/6", {
            method: "Post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                productOptions: {
                    stock: "14PT Printed 1 Side(4/0)",
                    size: "4 x 6",
                    qty: "50",
                    turnaround: "2 - 4 Business Days",
                    coating: "UV PG 1 Only",
                    bundling: "No Bundling - FREE",
                    scoring: "None",
                    sets: "1"
                }
            })
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.status)
                console.log(response.ok)
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)

            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
```

The output must show the price of the product.
I have tried to reduce the number of productOptions to:

```
 stock: "14PT Printed 1 Side(4/0)",
                    size: "4 x 6",
                    qty: "50",
                    turnaround: "2 - 4 Business Days",
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: have you read the API documentation? the price endpoint body is `productOptions: [optionIds...]` ... i.e. an Array?

Comment: Not sure how we can help with a 3rd party API that appear to require authorization.